# Object reference is required for HttpContext

Tags: c#, .net, object, reference, httpcontext

Beginner to C# here.

I am trying to return only the number of users in the same facility as the current user (unless that user is a manager).

I am getting a red line under `HttpContext.User` on the 2nd and 3rd lines that says

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'HttpContext.User'

I've tried researching this and none of those solutions, such as making the method static or calling it via `System.Web.HttpContext.User` have worked for me.

```
private int GetUsersforFacility(ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> Users)
{
     int userFacilityID = (int)HttpContext.User.GetFacilityId();
     bool manager = HttpContext.User.IsManager();

     if (!manager)
     {
          return Users.Where(user => user.FacilityID == userFacilityID).Count; 
     }

     return Users.Count;
}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: If this is .NET Framework (as opposed to "Core", 5+, etc): do you perhaps mean `HttpContext.Current.User`?

Comment: It is definitely HttpContext.User, I have that used in other files and when I hover over it, it recognizes HttpContext.User {get; set;}

Comment: and in those other scenarios, are you perhaps *in a controller*? i.e. the code is in an instance method in a class that has a property called `HttpContext`, so you're actually accessing `base.HttpContext.User` ? F12 over the existing `HttpContext` in the places where it works: I'm pretty sure it will take you to [`System.Web.Mvc.Controller.HttpContext`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.httpcontext) - and presumably in the code that is failing: *you're not in an instance method in a controller*, so you need to get it another way, i.e. `HttpContext.Current`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HttpContext` inside the controller is property inherited from `ControllerBase` and if you use it outside the controller `HttpContext` is just a class so only static members of it can be accessed.

In order to access it you have to pass through or inject `HttpContext` down the line.